# UITextRecognition getting the text upside down - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using the UIText recognition with the .accurate recognition type and it keeps reading the text flipped

for eg. instead of scanning 0606 it scans it as 9090

This is the piece of code

```
func setUpVisionTextRecognizingImage(image: UIImage){
        
        var textString = ""
        request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: {(request, error) in
            
            guard let observations = request.results as?[VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {fatalError("Recieved Invalid Observaton")}
            
                for observation in observations {
                
                guard let topCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else {print("No Candidate")
                continue
                }
                    textString = "\n\(topCandidate.string)"
                    print(textString)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.stopAnimating()
                            
                        let (testingVariable, isItFound) = (self.brain.getCode(uneditedCode: textString))
                        
                        
                        if isItFound == true {
                            
                            self.textLabel.text = testingVariable
                            self.buttonPressed(self)
                        }
                        else{self.showTryAgain(message: "try again")}

                        
                        
                    }}})
    
        request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    let requests = [request]
    
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            guard let img = image.cgImage else{fatalError("Missing Image to Scan")}
            let handle = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: img, options: [:])
            try?handle.perform(requests)
        }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Check your image in the correct direction or not.

Comment: @RajaKishan yes but it reads it upside down sometimes so I'm guessing it auto orient it to the text. Is there a way to make the detection always up portrait

Comment: No. You have to fix the orientation of the image. just search fix orientation + uiimage.

Comment: @RajaKishan THANKSSSS DUDE IT WORKED